# Using VB to open two specific .txt documents in excel, save the workbook as a certain name, and then reference the workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with a program I am writing that will open specific `.txt` documents in Excel and then save that workbook as a certain name which will be referenced in another excel workbook. The overall goal is to have like Workbook Main cell A3 reference a cell like B5 from Workbook Test1 that is created from text documents. So far I can pull up the most recent text document but I need the third most recent document as well in the same workbook.

So example: Folder `C:\Results` contains files:

```
Test1_Chr.txt
Test1_Ftr.txt
Test1_Hdr.txt
Test2_Chr.txt
Test2_Ftr.txt
Test2_Hdr.txt
```

I need to grab both the Test1 Chr and Hdr files and import them into an excel document. This is what I have so far for code (Note: It only works so far when the txt file has been created that same day I think as I have tried it one day and it was fine then the next without changing anything it stopped working)

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim MostRecentFile As String
Dim MostRecentFileHdr As String
Dim MostRecentDate As Date
Dim Path As String

Directory = "C:"
FileName = Dir(Directory & FileSpec, 0)
If FileName <> "" Then
   MostRecentFile = FileName
   MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
     Do While FileName <> ""
      If FileDateTime(Directory & FileName) > MostRecentDate Then
        MostRecentFile = FileName
        MostRecentDate = FileDateTime(Directory & FileName)
      End If
      FileName = Dir
    Loop
End If

Path = "C:\Results\"
NewestFile = Path + MostRecentFile

ChDir "C:\Results"
Workbooks.OpenText FileName:=NewestFile, Origin:= 437, StartRow:=1; 
DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, 
Tab:=True, Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=True, Other:=False, 
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1),etc... TrailingMinusNumbers:=True 
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-108
```

It looks like if the file was not created the same day I run the code it skips through the filename stuff and hops right to the array part.

Once I am able to get the most recent Hdr and Chr documents open on the same workbook regardless of when it was created I will then need to save it as the original name so Test1.xls would be the name of this one. I have tried using *_Hdr.txt and things like that but being fairly new to VB I am not sure if wildcards can be used like this in the type of application I want it to be used for.

I realize this is alot to ask for with the little information given but any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are searching for files in `C:` and opening files in `C:\Results`.

Comment: It mostly will be screaming that it couldn't find the file it was trying to open.

Comment: (1) Also this `StartRow:=1;` and `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1),etc...`  is no valid code. You need to give us the **exact** code you are using/trying (no changes!). Also the line breaks are messed up. Copy and paste the **exact** code from your VBA editor. (2) In your headline and text you are talking about VB which is not equal to VBA make sure which one you mean.